# Use variable in <img scr=

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have this code:

```
//This one gets the image from the first product in the product category category:

$catimg = get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->id, 'thumbnail' );

//This code contains custom text that also reads info from various variables, including the `$catimg` variable:

$cat_art1 =  '<h1>'.$variable1.' This is some text that will be outputted to my site.</h1>
Here i want to screen the image <img src="' . $catimg . '" alt="alt">
Some more text and another '.$variable.' to end the line';
```

I've tried various solutions from many google searches but none works for me as they all outputs the html tags. My output looks like this:

[image: Output from code]

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks!

Comment: What is in `$catimg`?

Comment: As the manual for `get_the_post_thumbnail()` says (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)  _"Return: (string) The post thumbnail image tag."_. It returns an img-tag, not just the URL. Your code adds an img-tag as source in an img-tag.

Comment: Something is telling me that $catimg contains a > character, telling the image tag that it ends there, thus printing alt=alt to your browser.

As @SougataBose said, can you echo out your $catimg and show us what is inside the variable?

Comment: Ah ignore my last, i didnt realise it's wordpress.

Change your $cat_art1 to:

'<h1>'.$variable1.' This is some text that will be outputted to my site.</h1>
Here i want to screen the image ' . $catimg . '
Some more text and another '.$variable.' to end the line';

Comment: $catimg = get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->id, 'thumbnail' ); what url you are getting

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the doc https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/ it return tag, not url.
To get the url, do

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
```

Go to doc https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/ for further informations ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think Your `$catimg` is returning nothing or blank string
I have tried this code in php fiddle with static image its working fine so your string interpolation is correct . Please Check your `$catimg` variable

```
<?php
//This one gets the image from the first product in the product category category:

$catimg = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/718314968102367232/ypY1GPCQ_400x400.jpg';
$variable1 = "Rajesh";
$variable = "Text";
//This code contains custom text that also reads info from various variables, including the `$catimg` variable:

$cat_art1 =  '<h1>'.$variable1.' This is some text that will be outputted to my site.</h1>
Here i want to screen the image <img src="' . $catimg . '" alt="alt">
Some more text and another '.$variable.' to end the line';
echo $cat_art1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference: To Get image url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_src( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false )


//This one gets the image from the first product in the product category category:

$catimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->id, 'thumbnail' ));

//This code contains custom text that also reads info from various variables, including the `$catimg` variable:

$cat_art1 =  '<h1>'.$variable1.' This is some text that will be outputted to my site.</h1>
Here i want to screen the image <img src="' . $catimg . '" alt="alt">
Some more text and another '.$variable.' to end the line';
```